# My postman is giving sending request and doing nothing for some values

Tags: node.js

This is my code in Node JS and I was using mysql

```
router.post('/districts', (req, res) => {
    const stateid = req.body.stateid;
    db.query("select id, name from lkup_district where stateid = '"+stateid+"' ", (error, rows) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        if(rows.length>0) {
            res.send(rows);
        }
    });
});
```

Using stateid I am getting the districts data. But if I send some stateid which was not present in lkup_districts, Postman is giving me loading and nothing happens. What's going wrong?

Should I write

```
if(rows.length=0) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look. You send answer on request only if you find something. If errors occurred or your request find nothing you do not send any data back. So, IMHO, you need to slightly modify your code. Something like

```
router.post('/districts', (req, res) => {
  const stateid = req.body.stateid;
  db.query(
      "select id, name from lkup_district where stateid = ? "
      ,[stateid], (error, rows) => {
          if(error) {
              console.log(error);
              res.status(500).send("Error proceeding query");
          }
          if(rows.length>0) {
              res.send(rows);
          }
          else {
              res.status(404).send("No data found");
          }

      }
  );
});
```

Comment: Ya thanks a lot, It's working as expected. But small doubt I am new to this JSON World so should i send the error too with some key:value pair?